# A good way to capture standard error and standard output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, logging

This works well except it merges the standard error stream into the standard out stream of the sourcing script.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Source this from a script to capture and `tee` standard error and standard 
# out to a log file. Calling script must source this script.  For Example:
#
# . /usr/bin/logy /var/log/project/$0.log
#
# The logging uses >(process substitution). Process substitution is supported 
# in shells like bash and zsh but is not supported in sh.

_LOG=${1?log file}
test $# -eq 1 || exit 1

mkdir -p "$(dirname "$_LOG")"

# Append stdout and stderr to log file
exec > >(
  echo -e "START\t$(date)" >> "$_LOG"
  tee -a "$_LOG"
  echo -e "END\t$(date)" >> "$_LOG"
) 2>&1
```

Here is an example:

```
. /usr/bin/logy $0.log
echo stdout
echo stderr >&2
exit 1
```

Run the script:

```
$ ./t
$ echo $?      # $? is the return value
1
```

Good, the return value 1 was preserved...

What was logged?

```
$ cat t.log
START    Thu, Feb 07, 2013  2:58:57 PM
stdout
stderr
END    Thu, Feb 07, 2013  2:58:57 PM
```

The idea is to make single log file and then use `logrotate` to maintain them.

Here is the issue.  The standard out and error streams were merged.  This outputs noting showing that the standard error stream went to standard out:

```
./t > /dev/null
```

This outputs both lines from the echo statements showing both went to standard out:

```
./t 2> /dev/null
```

Is there a good way to preserve the streams while preserving the order in the log file of the stdout/err statements?  For that reason, I don't think two `exec` statements are an option.

Comment: Short answer: no.  Simply copying the output of a script (and the error stream) into a file is *not* logging.  Wrapping dates around it does not make it logging.  Formatting it does not make it logging.  output is output, error messages are error messages, and a log is a log.  They are different things.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix my subject...  You make a good point, I needed to narrow the requirement.  It is not a model logging example, we just need a way to watch everything that is going on.

Comment: (1) I'll note that process substitution is not a bash-only feature. [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) supports it also. (2) What's your question? It looks like your script works as designed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good sir, this should work

```
script_name.sh |& tee -a /var/log/script_name.sh.log
```

To [**clarify**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) part of the command

```
|& was added to Bash 4 as an abbreviation for 2>&1 |
```